# Why doesn't rospack list runtime dependencies?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, package.xml, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following dependencies specified in the `package.xml` file

```
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

<build_depend>message_filters</build_depend>
<build_depend>rosbag</build_depend>
<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
<build_depend>tf</build_depend>

<build_export_depend>message_filters</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>rosbag</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>tf</build_export_depend>

<exec_depend>message_filters</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>rosbag</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>tf</exec_depend>

<exec_depend>python-h5py</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>python-opencv</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>python-pandas</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>python-tqdm</exec_depend>
```

Then I issue `catkin build` inside my workspace. I also do `rosdep install my_package`. However, when I do `rospack depends1 my_package`, I only see `message_filters`, `rosbag`, `rospy` and `tf`. Why is that the case?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333585/why-doesn%27t-rospack-list-runtime-dependencies?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2019-09-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Why doesn't rospack list runtime dependencies?

it does, but `rospack` only lists dependencies of your package that are *ROS packages*.

That's why you "only see `message_filters`, `rosbag`, `rospy` and `tf`" when you ran `rospack depends1 my_package`.

If you want to list system dependencies -- which your `python-*` keys are -- you'd need to run `rosdep`.

`rospack` does have a proxy for that, so you should get the output you are looking for by running:

```
rospack rosdep my_package
```

For `roscpp`, we get:

```
user@machine:/# rospack rosdep roscpp
name: apr
name: boost
name: cmake
name: google-mock
name: gtest
name: libconsole-bridge-dev
name: log4cxx
name: pkg-config
name: python-argparse
name: python-catkin-pkg
name: python-empy
name: python-mock
name: python-nose
name: python-yaml
```

while we get a different list with just `rospack depends`:

```
cpp_common
message_runtime
rosconsole
roscpp_serialization
roscpp_traits
rosgraph_msgs
rostime
std_msgs
xmlrpcpp
```

which are the ROS packages that `roscpp` depends on.

> Please, do not tell me that I need to do `pip install pandas`, when there is this mentioned article http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/python_module_dependencies.html!

Using `pip` is never something anyone should recommend, especially not on platforms with a proper package manager.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-09-22**:
You did not answer my question about **not** being able to import pandas, even if I did `rosdep install my_package`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-22**:
The question title is:

> Why doesn't rospack list runtime dependencies?

I explained what you observed.